# FFMPEG - Audio conversion from MP3 to M3u8 works for some songs, not for others. Look's like it's detecting video?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

Problem: I need to convert MP3s (of unknown Origin) into M3u8 files so that I can HLS stream them.

This command here works for a song called 'jesussaves.mp3'

`ffmpeg -i ../jesussaves.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 2 -f hls -hls_time 10 -preset ultrafast -flags -global_header master.m3u8`

When I change it to use the song 'In my Darkest Hour' - (I've renamed the file to inmydh.mp3) - I only get one TS file output instead of multiple. The log is here: https://ibb.co/5nG0j01

Thank you

Comment: FFmpeg treats album cover art as a video track.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use "-map 0:a" to avoid video

Comment: Thank you very much.